# OP answering his/her own question right after posting it

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, acceptable-questions

I'm referring to [what are the essential aspects of the Keynes revolution in economic theory are?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/21748/42)

The question is asked on 2018-04-30 14:58:50 and the OP supplied an answer to it less than three minutes later at 15:01:21. It appears that OP's answer is a direct copy-and-paste from [an article by Hyman Minsky](http://digitalcommons.bard.edu/hm_archive/19/) (the 3rd paragraph of the Introduction section).

It also appears that the OP is an unregistered user. All these suggest that the particular Q&A initiated by the OP is somewhat disingenuous.

Would the community find such disingenuous behavior acceptable? Should it be encouraged/discouraged? The question itself seems legitimate (though it could be better formatted) and OP's answer is largely valid. And I'm not against answering one's own question in general. It is the disingenuity, as well as the apparent lack of interest/commitment to this site, that bugs me a little.

Comment: I was considering if we should have standards with regards to the quality of content on the site.Though its within my power to just delete and ban posts like this i don't know if other senior users would agree with me. Seems like plagiarism to me.

Comment: @EconJohn: Yes, using other's work without proper citation is precisely plagiarism. I refrained from using that term because i) it is only a secondary concern for me, and ii) I'm afraid there's not much to be done about it here.

Comment: The site's resident troll has a fixation on Keynes. He resurfaces every now and then. See [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/does-keynesianism-increase-the-incentive-to-invest). I think this is just another incarnation. The meta question is still valid, but this instance is probably disingenuous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

General practice on the SE network seems to be to take a permissive attitude to users who answer their own questions. Our [FAQ says](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer):

> **Can I answer my own question?**
>
> Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.
>
> To encourage people to do this, there is a checkbox at the bottom of the page every time you ask a question. If you have more than 15 reputation and already know the answer, click the checkbox that says "Answer your own question" at the bottom of the Ask Question page. Type in your answer, then submit both question and answer together.
>
> Alternatively, you may go back and add an answer to your own question at any time.
>
> You can also accept your own answer, but you must wait 48 hours to do so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem!

The site also incentivises this behaviour with the award of [a badge](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/14/self-learner).

It seems like the bottom line is whether the question/answer brings good quality content to the site or not. It looks like the post in question might fail this test given the plagiarised answer and the lazy copy-paste question. Self-answers should be held to an equally high standard as all other answers on the site.